# Email response Handling

Tags: laravel, email

how can i handel the email verification api response? I got such type of response that is laravel built in response, as mentioned below but i want user friendly and human readable response like "please verify email fitst"
Laravel response=Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [verification.notice] not defined. in file C:\Users\touse\Desktop\pj_backend_new\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 479

i want to add a job but i add the verification of email if the user is not verified then i give me a error it workrs well but when it return response that is not user frieldy.how can i handel the email verification api response? I got such type of response that is laravel built in response, as mentioned below but i want user friendly and human readable response like "please verify email fitst"
Laravel response=Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [verification.notice] not defined. in file C:\Users\touse\Desktop\pj_backend_new\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 479

Comment: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: What kind of "API" do you talk about? If a route is not defined, that's not a problem related to mailing itself

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you've implemented the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` on the `User` model.

When you do this, you need to add some configuration to your application, including adding some routes.

According to the current [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/verification#the-email-verification-notice), you need to add a route named `verification.notice`. And because this named route doesn't exist, you end up with that specific error.

You can either manage the required routes yourself, or use some of the existing Laravel application starter kits.

But ultimately, the reason why you get that error, is because the named route doesn't exist in your application.

Comment: I solved it by making a custom middleware it easily sort out my issue.

Comment: you are right that need the route which is not exist.